# How can I show the tab bar in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way to force-show the tab bar in Notepad++ when in notepad-mode?  That is, when I have the asNotepad.xml file in the Notepad++ executable directory?

Comment: What's the point of this? Notepad isn't MDI; that's why Notepad++'s Notepad mode hides the tab bar by default.

Comment: @BoltClock I'd like to be able to show the tab bar in Notepad++ when dragging multiple files into a Notepad++ window. But I would also like to open a new Notepad++ instance when double-clicking a file from Explorer.

Comment: Hm, I just noticed that you'd asked this a short while back... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774292/is-there-a-way-to-force-multiple-tabs-while-using-asnotepad-xml-in-notepad

Comment: I guess this question should have been posted on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 93):

The latest version of Notepad++ (v6.5) allows you to select whether to hide the tab bars. It's under `Settings` > `Preference` > `General` > `Tab Bar`

[image]

Comment: I've been using Np++ for decades on multiple comps. Why would it all of a sudden enable this ckbx to disappear ?

Comment: I just installed update Notepad++ v7.7.1. I've always used Notepad++ with may files open and many tabs showing. The install of this new v7.7.1 version set the "Hide" checkbox to true as per this setting and thus I had to search for how to get back to the standard way I work with many files via many tabs ..  Normally an install would honour a persons previous settings for the application? No matter, minor thing.

Answer (score 2):

What you should NOT do is hide the tab bar, and remove the `asNotepad.xml` file. If you do these things you will NEVER have the tab bar.

What you should do instead is setup the appropriate file associations in the Preferences so that notepad++ will simply be the default application for those file extensions.